# Java.Android.Переход на главную страничку

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app, page

Есть вторичная страничка программы . В форме есть кнопка home , которая **должна** перенести пользователя на главную страничку(**которая загружается первой**) . Как это **можно** реализовать , если данный способ не работает :

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.example.x.myfirstnormal.MainActivity");
                        startActivity(intent2);
```

(срабатывающий код после нажатии кнопки , где MainActivity - главная страничка)
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо просто вернуться к предыдущей активности, то можно пойти и таким путем:

```
 android:parentActivityName="com.example.x.myfirstnormal.MainActivity"
```

Это нужно указать в манифесте приложения у второй активити и благодаря этому, в `ActionBar` второй активити появится стрелка *назад*.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Первым параметром в конструктор `Intent` нужно передавать контекст. В случае, если вызов происходит из активити, можно передавать `this`, в остальных случаях — например, из анонимного класса — нужно явно вызывать контекст.

Официальный гайд: [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Comment: Не работает.Если убрать слово class , будет выделено красной линией только MainActivity.Вся ошибка :Error:(26, 41) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnClickListener>,Class<MainActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: Я попытался сделать так  Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity2.this , MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2); Но не помогло . Ошибки нету,но не переносит на **главную страничку программы,которая запускается в самом начале**

Comment: @True-hacker, если у Вас всего две `Activity`, то достаточно закрыть вторую, чтобы вернуться в первую: `MainActivity2.this.finish();`

Comment: первым аргументом должен быть контекст. в данном случае интент вызывается из анонимного слушателя и this указывает именно на него, а не на контекст. Про этот момент стоит написать отдельно, что из фрагментов, анонимных классов (колбэков) и прочих "не активити" контекст нужно указывать явно